# TypeScript Implied Generic

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this class and I wonder if i can simplify this:

```
export class A<TB extends B<TC>, TC> implements TD<TB, TC> {
  make(): TC {}
}
```

Because right now, I need to set the TC type whenever I want to create an A, like this:

```
class CTest {}
class BTest extends B<CTest> {}

const a = new A<BTest, CTest>();
a.make() // -> CTest
```

That TC type is already a generic type argument of B tho. Is there a way to reduce this, so it would end up looking something like this:

```
export class A<TB extends B<TC>> implements TD<TB, TC> {
  make(): TC {}
}

class CTest {}
class BTest extends B<CTest> {}

const a = new A<BTest>();
a.make() // -> CTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The general way to extract a generic parameter is like this.

For a given interface that incorporates a generic type, like so:

```
type C = {c:number}

interface B<TC> {x:TC}
```

You can extract the generic using a conditional type with infer:

```
type ExtractC<T> = T extends B<infer TC> ? TC : never
```

And so for the type with the generic:

```
type BX = B<C>
```

You can extract the generic parameter:

```
type Y = ExtractC<BX> // type Y inferred as {c:number}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeBjAXAOwK4FsBGEATgL4BQpAlhsEQGYCGK0AQgDwAqMAfMgB5qcypUJCgBRXsEKNgMDj0TsoESRAwATAM5Q2VWkSiceAfkNw0UDBABuRciJYANBDtbd74aAE0XEqTLlmRx4AehCoBygfPSIIdSh6bVRMXAISIA).

What `infer TC` means in the expression above is, basically, "TC is whatever type is found here".  In other words you can think of `infer TC` as creating a new variable that you can then use in your conditional assignment.  This is why a lot of times you will see it written as `infer X`, which is suggestive of the "variable-like" nature of the type inferred via the infer statement.

I think with this info you should be able to simplify your type easily.  But if you want to post a playground of your code, I'm happy to give further pointers.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what i was searching for!